# Network traffic with standard ASP.NET applications

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, traffic

I've been learning about AJAX and jQuery to build web applications and now I see how powerful are these tools. Because this, some questions about the network traffic gennerated by standard ASP.NET applications without those techniques came up.

It is known that every control that has the runat="server" property setted, puts on the viewstate it's current values, which is codified and placed inside a hidden input on the response to the user.

However, every little action on the page triggers a post to the server, sending back the entire page's values. Depending on the complexity of the page, it may be very dangerous to the application because it would generate a lot of traffic unnecessarily.

An example: i've build a page that it's size is about 155kb rendered (62kb only is the viewstate). So, every post on the page returns a new rendered page with similar size, even it's contents does not changed. Inside an Intranet environment, it seems nothing, but on the web it would be inappropriate.

What do you think about this question? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that if you don't like the purely server-side nature of vanilla ASP.NET, you should just include the very techniques you mentioned.  There is lots of documentation and many step-by-step guides to help you understand how to use a mix of client side and server side techniques with ASP.NET.

What do i think about this question? Which question? I'm not sure you have a question other than your question about your mystery question.

I'll just leave this here: http://www.asp.net/ajax